# Making a timer in Python 3.3

Tags: python, timer

I need a little hand with my project.

Ive got the majority of it sorted, except one vital detail.

I am trying to have it so that the program will time the time it takes for an input (in seconds)

This is how it should function

```
Please enter the name:
=Bob
Please press enter when Bob has crossed the line (should time this)
= <enter pressed>
Bob took x seconds.
```

Thanks all

Comment: See time.time()

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html#time.time

Answer (score 4):

Use the time module. First, import time:

```
import time
```

Then, assign a variable to be time.time():

```
a = time.time()
```

time.time(), strangely enough, calls the exact number of seconds since midnight on January 1, 1970. This, by itself, is not very useful. But this can be used with subtraction to time things. Call the input function, which will stop the program until enter is pressed.

```
var = input("Press enter when bob has crossed the line")
```

Then, call the time.time function again. Say, the first time you call it, time is 1421174642.25. The second time it is called, time could be a another number, say, 1421174699.42. Store this in a DIFFERENT variable:

```
b = time.time()
```

This will store the value of time.time() at that moment. The difference between the two will be equal to the elapsed time. Let's assign another variable, c, to this.

```
c = b - a
```

If a was 1421174642.25, and b was 1421174699.42, b - a , or c, is 57.17. Make this a whole number by calling int() on c, like this:

```
d = int(c)
```

Finally, print d, with the rest of the sentence.

```
print "Bob took " + d + " seconds."
```

this, in our case, will return:

> Bob took 57 seconds.

Comment: That's a long answer.

Comment: Long but verbose... and I like verbose.  +1.  If you check out some of my answers, my answers are rarely less than 2 paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) module:

```
import time

start = time.time() 
inp = input("Bob Please press enter when Bob has crossed the line")
end = time.time()
print("Bob took {:.2f} seconds. Thanks all".format(end-start))
```